# Log4j2 Appender attributes with strict xml config

Tags: log4j2

I'm using log4j2-beta9 and want to configure it using a log4j2.xml in strict mode.
My issue is: how do I specify attributes that are not in the shipped schema file?
An Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Configuration
    status="DEBUG"
    strict="true"
    monitorInterval="5"
    name="TestingAttributes"
    verbose="true"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="Log4j-config.xsd">
    <Properties>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Appender
            type="Console"
            name="SYSERR"
            target="SYSTEM_ERR"> <!-- cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'target' is not allowed to appear in element 'Appender'. -->
            <Layout Type="PatternLayout">
                <Pattern>%date{dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %logger %m%n</Pattern>
            </Layout>
            <Filters>
                <Filter
                    type="MarkerFilter"
                    marker="FLOW"
                    onMatch="DENY"

                    onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
                <Filter
                    type="MarkerFilter"
                    marker="EXCEPTION"
                    onMatch="DENY"
                    onMismatch="NEUTRAL" />
            </Filters>
        </Appender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="SYSERR" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Notice that I want to set the appender to have the target `SYSTEM_ERR` but the attribute is not allowed in strict mode.

```
target="SYSTEM_ERR"> <!-- cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'target' is not allowed to appear in element 'Appender'. -->
```

I could always edit the `Log4j-config.xsd` and allow that attribute there but that would be kind of wrong also because not all appenders have a `target` attribute.

As searching the web didn't help me so far, I'm asking you:
Is there anything I'm missing in configuring Log4j2 in strict XML mode?

Do I have to "patch" the XMLConfiguration and the schema file and commit a change to log4j or is there another way besides not using strict mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you ask this on the log4j-user mailing list? It could be a bug in the schema, but I suspect the schema can do with more improvements and your feedback would be valuable.

Comment: Have done that... see http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4j-user/201310.mbox/%3C399C55D178537F4FB31E4F8F6A8AE1ECCD8B8D@mscas.materna.com%3E